# Controlling Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 screen lock with arduino

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, lock-screen, arduino

I am trying to use arduino with my laptop (Ubuntu-gnome 16.04 installed) to control the screen lock using RFID Module (Screen lock/unlock is controlled by an RFID card)

Here in this particular case, I trigger some action in arduino (swiping of RFID card) which should be able to perform the following tasks:

1. Lock the screen.
2. Unlock the locked screen (obviously without asking for password).

I want to get task number 2 done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured a way out.

Keep a python script running at the background and use the `serial` library in python to connect to a particular serial port. Now `serial write` the data from arduino whenever the desired action in executed in arduino. Read the value written on serial in python script and based on that value execute shell command for locking and unlocking the system, which are as follows:

`gnome-screensaver-command -l` (to lock)

`gnome-screensaver-command -d` (to unlock)

Python code:

```
import serial, os
port_name = '/dev/ttyACM0' # Change accordingly
arduino = serial.Serial(port_name, 9600)
while True:
    word = str(arduino.readline())
    if word == 'l': # Lock the screen
        os.system('gnome-screensaver-command -l')
    elif word == 'u': # Unlock the screen
        os.system('gnome-screensaver-command -d')
```

Now using `Serial.write()` function of arduino, write `'l'` or `'u'` on the serial based on your requirement (RFID Swipe as in my case).

Happy Hacking :-)

Comment: it gives me that `/dev/tty*` device is busy which Arduino is listening. Should I bring up another serial for this script?

Comment: mutliple serials are possible in Arduino Mega and higher, did you get this working with Arduino Uno R3?